# GParted does not resize the partition on a .img file?

Tags: partitioning, gparted, dd, loop-device

I am backing up data from an old hard drive one partition at a time to .img files using dd.

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sdc5 of=/home/flex/data/partition.img bs=1M status=progress
```

This gives me a 10GB .img file but I know there is only 3GB data on the partition.

The partition is FAT32 and contains a Windows XP OS.

I loop mount the .img file... it appears at /dev/loop7

```
sudo losetup --find partition.img
```

Then open in GParted..

```
sudo gparted /dev/loop7
```

Now in Gparted when I go to resize the partition it appears to work and gives no errors but I don't think it actually changes anything. The .img file is still 10GB and this command shows that the size of the partition is still 10GB..

```
sudo parted /dev/loop7 unit s print free
```

I thought there would unallocated partition space that I could then do...

```
truncate --size=$[(End Sector+1)*512] partition.img
```

What am I doing wrong?

I guess my alternative is to TAR the whole partition.img and then extract to a blank .img file but I want to know if this method with GParted is possible because it seems like a convenient way to resize a .img file for storage.

Cheers,

Flex

Answer (score 0):

My problem with GParted not re-sizing the partition was because of the way I was extracting each partition individually from my old hard drive each into a separate .img file for each partition.

sudo dd `if=/dev/sdc5`...

This was giving me a `partition.img` file that had no partition table or partition either, just the filesystem.

So now I follow these steps instead...

-- Create a blank .img file that is large enough to contain the partition you extract from the old HDD. E.g: 12GB.

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=Win-XP-New-12G.img bs=1M count=12000
```

-- Loop mount that file and find out what loop device it got with `lsblk` (/dev/loop7 in this case)

```
sudo losetup --find Win-XP-New-12G.img
lsblk
```

-- Create a partition table in the 12GB .img file then create a partition then format that partition as fat32 (the partition I was archiving from the old HDD is FAT32)

```
sudo parted -s /dev/loop7 mklabel msdos
sudo parted -s /dev/loop7 mkpart primary fat32 2048s 100%
sudo mkfs -t vfat /dev/loop7p1
```

-- With the old HDD connected to my Ubuntu laptop via USB I find the device file of the partition I want using `lsblk`
-- Copy the data from the HDD partition `/dev/sdc5` DIRECTLY INTO the PARTITION in the 12GB .img file. e.g: `/dev/loop7p1` below

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sdc5 of=/dev/loop7p1 bs=1M status=progress
```

-- Now open the device file that points to the 12GB .img file in GParted to re-size the partition to make it smaller. This time the GParted re-size worked and later I truncated the .img file [Great help from here](https://itectec.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-re-size-the-img-for-smaller-sd-card-how-to-shrink-a-bootable-sd-card-image/).

```
sudo gparted /dev/loop7
```

I did not go with the `tar` or `rsync` commands because they do not preserve accessed or create timestamps when copying files to a Fat32 filessytem.